# Dataflow jobs failing and showing no logs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-logging

I created pipelines in Dataflow using the standard template `JDBC to BigQuery` and there are a few jobs that are unexpectedly failing and not showing any logs.

The thing is, when a job fails because of the resources, the job needed more vCPUs than was avaliable in the region or the memory was not enough for example, these kind of errors are displayed in the logs, as you can see below.

[image]

But some jobs just fail with no logs and the resources are sufficient.

[image]

Does anyone know how to find the logs in this case?

Comment: Your first screenshot seems to have logs with exceptions regarding the JDBC connections. I know you said there were resource errors, but just from the screenshot I think your problem is related to JDBC connection problems.

Answer (score 2):

Change the severity of the logs. If you choose `Default`, you should see more logs. For how the job page looks like for that failed job, I would say you are probably going to need to have a look at the worker logs as well.

Depending on the error, the *Diagnostics* tab may have some summarized info of what kind error has made the job fail.

Answer (score 1):

The log viewer within Dataflow console seems to be broken. However, you can get to the error logs by going to the Logs console at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query;query=resource.type%3D%22dataflow_step%22;

Comment: It is not the only problem like this. Also TFX and PyTorch components in GCP does not display component logs in GCP Vertex, making the debugging very problematic. It is surprising that such an important issue it was not resolved so far.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/6539